# How to make 2 Domains for 1 Site (No redirect)

Tags: .htaccess, dns, aliases

How to use 2 Domain for 1 Site (No redirect).
for example:

site1.com
site2.com

All of these 2 domain work for ONE site without redirect but the files and database inside (site1.com) only.

and when using site2.com the title for any pages it's same when using site1.com

Thanks

Comment: For example:

example.com (Old Domain) and the files inside it.
example.net (New Domain) and no files inside it.

I want: when I go to example.net/admin no redirect to example.com/admin , Should be still example.net/admin and everything work fine.

How to do that.

Comment: Welcome to Stackverflow Ali. The comment you've added is relevant to the intent of your question, so it would be good to edit the question to include that detail.

Comment: Make sure that all links around the site are relative URLs (i.e. starting with `/` rather than `https://`

Answer (score 0):

Edit site2.com A Record in DNS.

If site1.com has in DNS als: site1.com. -- A -- 187.11.200.1
then set in site2.com DNS settings als: site2.com. -- A -- 187.11.200.1

Reply this with all www and subdomain too.

Sorry for my bad english... :)

.htaccess on site2.com (Redirect)

```
Redirect 301 / https://site1.com/
```

Comment: It's in .htaccess not in DNS Records.
Thank you for reply.

Comment: Edited with .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Avoid doing what you are asking. However, if you insist, I have done this before, playing with servers for self-educational purposes.

### New question

I could translate the original question to this:
*"How to serve two different domains (hosted in the same server) with the same documents: HTML, PHP, static files, and so forth"*.

### Shared Hosting

If you are working in shared hosting, you could define the `DocumentRoot` for the second domain (site2.com) to be the same as site1.com.
You can do this only the moment you add the add-on domain.
Ex. use `~/public_html/` and not `~/public_html/site2.com/` as the web control panel will probably suggest you.

If you already added the second domain to point to a different directory, then remove it and add it again.
¡¡¡ Be careful with email accounts, and other setups you had already made for that domain !!!

### Admin Access

If you are in a VPS or some other hosting system with root or admin access, then you could edit de `vhost` configuration file of the two domains (or maybe the `vhost` file of only one domain).

**Apache**

Locate the `vhosts` directory:
`/etc/httpd/conf.d/vhosts`, or
`/usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts/`, or
find the right configuration for your system.

You should see the configuration files: `site1.com.conf` and `site2.com.conf`.
Edit those files by changing the `DocumentRoot` to point to the same directory.
Attention, other lines must be edited.

**NGINX**

Locate the `vhosts` directory: `/etc/nginx/conf.d/vhosts/`.
Edit the corresponding configuration files in the line that begins with `location`  and probably the line with the directive `disable_symlinks if_not_owner`.